# How to make this jquery function reusable?

Tags: jquery, function, click, anchor

Hai this is my jquery function,

```
function getRecordspage(curPage, pagSize) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetRecords",
        data: "{'currentPage':" + curPage + ",'pagesize':" + pagSize + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(jsonObj) {
            var strarr = jsonObj.d.split('##');
            var jsob = jQuery.parseJSON(strarr[0]);
            $.each(jsob.Table, function(i, employee) {
                $('<div class="resultsdiv"><br /><span class="resultName">' + employee.Emp_Name + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:100px;">Category&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Desig_Name + '</span><br /><br /><span id="SalaryBasis" class="resultfields">Salary Basis&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.SalaryBasis + '</span><span class="resultfields" style="padding-left:25px;">Salary&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.FixedSalary + '</span><span style="font-size:110%;font-weight:bolder;padding-left:25px;">Address&nbsp;:</span>&nbsp;<span class="resultfieldvalues">' + employee.Address + '</span></div>').appendTo('#ResultsDiv');
            });
            $(".resultsdiv:even").addClass("resultseven");
            $(".resultsdiv").hover(function() {
                $(this).addClass("resultshover");
            }, function() {
                $(this).removeClass("resultshover");
            });
        }
    });
}
```

In my page i have this jquery script,

```
$("#lnkbtn0").click(function() {
                 getRecordspage(1, 5)
            });
```

And my page has

`<a ID="lnkbtn0" class="page-numbers">1</a>`
`<a ID="lnkbtn1" class="page-numbers">2</a>`
`<a ID="lnkbtn2" class="page-numbers">3</a>`
`<a ID="lnkbtn3" class="page-numbers">4</a>`

How to make other link buttons to call this function with diff `curPage` parameter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean you want to apply the text of links with ID starting with **linkbtn** as the first parameter:

```
$("a[id^=linkbtn]").click(function() {
    getRecordspage($(this).text(), 5);
    return false;
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Alternatively, you could just use a class selector:

```
$("a.page-numbers").click(function() {
    getRecordspage($(this).text(), 5);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using Plain old javascript

```
<a ID="lnkbtn0" class="page-numbers" href="#" onclick="getRecordsPage(1,5)">1</a>
<a ID="lnkbtn1" class="page-numbers" href="#" onclick="getRecordsPage(2,5)">2</a>
<a ID="lnkbtn2" class="page-numbers" href="#" onclick="getRecordsPage(3,5)">3</a>
<a ID="lnkbtn3" class="page-numbers" href="#" onclick="getRecordsPage(4,5)">4</a>
```

Make sure you `preventDefault` on the `<a>` tags.

Else, if you really want to go JQuery.

```
$("a[id^=linkbtn]").each(function() {
   $(this).click(function() {
       getRecordspage($(this).text(), 5);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE** Use class selectors (as karim79) suggested.

Comment: @Elite i ll go with jquery should i use href="#" for my anchors

Comment: Some browsers refresh the page if no `href` is found. You can do `href="javascript: void(0)"` to essentially do nothing. It's essentially up to you to choose which browser you want.